# Access the DOM element in React Native

Tags: react-native

What is the alternative to `document.getElementById` in React Native? I want to access the element in the DOM. I am using a functional component.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `refs`. Lets say you have a div, and you want to get a DOM reference.

```
  const MyFuncComp = React.memo(() => {
    const divRef = React.useRef(null)
    
    /* your other logic here */
    /* refer the div node using divRef.current - its the HTML DOM Node.

    return (
      <div ref={divRef.current}>
        // whatever you want to render
      </div>
    )
  })
```

Resources: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html